# How can I save websites without images in Firefox, by default?

Tags: firefox

I would like to save websites as html, without any images, by default (instead of "website, complete").

I have already set `permissions.default.image` to `2`, but that does not seem to affect it at all.

Comment: You do understand not every website can be saved as HTML, if their content isn't generated by HTML, then it cannot be saved by HTML.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm confused. Are you referring to e.g. a HTML site generated by (for instance) PHP? That could be saved just fine.

Comment: I am not talking about PHP websites.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, what do you mean then? I cannot picture what you refer to. Alas, the websites I want to save can be saved nicely, so they luckily do not suffer from it.